# CakePHP beforeFind causing resetAssociations, preventing ContainableBehavior

Tags: cakephp-2.4

In my User model I have the function beforeFind, which adds conditions with data pulled from an associated model (TenantsUser).

The problem is when this is used in conjunction with ContainableBehavior.
First, when find is called, ContainableBehaviors setup routine is called which modifies the associations of User (as expected).
Then, in my User/beforeFilter function I call TenantsUser which performs another find() call. However, at the end of the find call it resets the associations of all related models (User included), and this resets the association building that the ContainableBehavior has done, so my find returns all associations, not those specified within Contains.

Any idea on how to get around this?

Answer (score 0):

If you could post some code with the data set you're seeing and an explanation of what you'd expect to see instead it would be easier to help you. Without this it's basically impossible to troubleshoot. I'm assuming you've searched unsuccessfully for answers on the Internet already, which means your problem might be new, so more information is critical. Be sure to include your model files with the association definitions.

Also you mention using `beforeFind` and then `beforeFilter`; is this a typo or are you using both these callbacks?

Have you read through the `bindModel` functionality here?

http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/associations-linking-models-together.html#creating-and-destroying-associations-on-the-fly

That said, I've always found the containable behaviour to be very counter-intuitive. If you're just looking for something that works instead of leveraging CakePHP's built-in functionality, try using `hasMany through` associations, and doing the lookups on the linking table (if you're linking `Tenant` and `User` you'd do the `find` on the `TenantsUser` table).

Answer (score 0):

I ended up unbinding and rebinding models to get around my issue, the following code is within beforeFind()

```
// If this function is being called with ContainableBehavior being used, then the associations of User
// have already been adjusted to perform the query correctly. However, after find() functions are executed,
// models, and their associated models have their associations reset to defaults.
// Because we execute TenantsUser->find by calling the function below, TenantsUser will reset the associations
// within the User model thereby destroying all the work that ContainableBehavior did.
// For this reason, before calling TenantsUser->find(), we unbind the User Model from the TenantsUser Model, which means
// that the Users associations are NOT reset.
$this->TenantsUser->unbindModel(
        array('belongsTo' => array('User')),
        false   // We have to force the unbind to remain, otherwise the associations will be reset.
    );  

$user_ids = $this->TenantsUser->getUserIdsForTenant($this->getCurrentTenantId(), $tenants_users_statuses);

// Rebind the model.
$this->TenantsUser->bindModel(
    array('belongsTo' => array('User'))
);
```